# SQL query with temporary column showing the first 4 characters of the date column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

instead of displaying the whole date i only want to display the first 4 characters of the date column.

```
SELECT Test.Date From Test
```

wanting Date to be limited to 4 characters long

Comment: `Test.Date` is of what type? 4 characters because you only want the year?

Comment: format is datetime, i simply want the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the year.

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) as Year FROM Test
```

or you can also use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y') as Year FROM Test
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT LEFT(Test.Date, 4) FROM Test`

Should work just fine, assuming the format is "2013-04-10"